# Comments for my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, comments

I have created my iPhone App and i must do a document like javaDoc in java but i don't find anything with google.
I think that the comments have similar syntax but i'm not sure. (/*    */)

Can you help me? 
Thanks

Comment: duplicate: see the following for alternative using HeaderDoc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813529/documentation-generator-for-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `//` for single line comments, or `/** */` for multi-line comments.

You'd also be wise to make use of `#pragma mark` to further organize your code. See here: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html

There are also tools like Doxygen: hhttp://www.doxygen.nl

Comment: and the last question, i must add the comments for the .h or for the .h and .m ???

Comment: You can add them however you want. I would recommend looking at some of Apple's example code to see how they document things. A header file is supposed to provide a contract for the class, so much of your documentation will go there.

Answer (score 3):

As Peter said above, there is `DOxygen` and then also [DOxyClean](http://github.com/mattball/doxyclean) which cleans it up a bit.  More info here: http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html

Comments can either be like this

```
// this is a comment above some line of code
if (foo != 0) { 
    // do something 
}
```

or like this

```
/*
// look ma, i'm commenting out a bunch of code

if (foo != 0) {
   // do something here
}

*/
```

or like this

```
// TODO: i'm marking something that will show up as a To-Do item in XCode's drop down list
```

and i think there's another one but I can't remember off hand

Comment: As an example of this, Core Plot uses Doxygen to generate its framework documentation: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/DocumentationPolicy

Answer (score 0):

The answer about Doxygen was right on back when it was written, but since then Appledoc has come a long way.  It can now generate documentation that actually integrates with the popup dialogs that looks very close to the official documentation.

I would highly advise folks to use Appledoc going forward instead of Doxygen.

http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/

PS - Doxygen is still a great product, and can be used for other things.  It's just not the best for iOS projects anymore.