# How to do the documentation in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, documentation

Could anyone share the the ways to do the documentation in objective C? Is there any standard way like it is in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Documentation-generator for Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813529/documentation-generator-for-objective-c)

Comment: well.. actually I am looking for some tutorials for writing documentations in objective C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what IDE you're using but [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) lets you generate documentation from comments in Objective-C (as well as C, C++, Java, and some others).

If you're using Xcode (just assuming, since you're using Objective-C), there does seem to be some level of integration (not tested by me, just found on Google): http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html

Answer (score 8):

Good news for all! :D Finally after waiting a long time Apple has introduced a parser comments for our projects. According to the [new features](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html) in XCode 5:

> Project documentation from framework API reference documentation and
>   structured comments in your own source code are displayed in the quick
>   help panel and in code completion popover views. Doxygen and HeaderDoc
>   structured comments are supported formats.

and from the [Clang 3.2](http://llvm.org/releases/3.2/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#majorfeatures) release notes:

> Clang parses the comments and can detect syntactic and semantic errors
>   in comments. These warnings are off by default. Pass -Wdocumentation
>   flag to enable warnings about documentation comments.

If you want to see an example of this new feature I recommend you take a look at the following article: [Documentation in Xcode 5](http://confusatory.org/post/63488534619/documentation-in-xcode-5?utm_source=iOS%20Dev%20Weekly&utm_campaign=iOS_Dev_Weekly_Issue_115&utm_medium=email)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19169271/991816). It lists all supported commands.

Answer (score 3):

The *standard* way, as @DiegoPalomar suggested, is to use **HeaderDoc**, Apple's own tool for embedding structured comments in source code.

It comes with Xcode, so no installation required. It comes with a command-line script that generates HTML output of your documentation.

Docs for HeaderDoc:

- [Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html)
- [HeaderDoc command-line tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/usage/usage.html)
- [HeaderDoc markup](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html)

Here's an example:

```
/*!
 *  Takes in a number and adds 4 to it.
 *
 *  @param myNumber a number of type NSInteger.
 *
 *  @return The number with 4 added to it.
 */
- (NSInteger)addFour:(NSInteger)myNumber {
    return myNumber + 4;
}
```

Big plus: when you alt-click on your documented method, your doc appears in the balloon:

[image]

HeaderDoc is open-source too: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/headerdoc/

Comment: First 3 links are not working.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`Doxygen`](http://www.doxygen.nl/).