# JavaDoc-like documentation for Objective-C in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation, xcode4, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do the documentation in objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374535/how-to-do-the-documentation-in-objective-c)

Is it possible to write class/method documentation in Objective-C in a way that Xcode 4 displays them in the quick help, and/or generates a doc document from it in the style of Apple's own documentation?

Comment: Possible dupes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374535/how-to-do-the-documentation-in-objective-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813529/documentation-generator-for-objective-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525038/what-tools-might-i-use-for-generating-documentation-for-an-xcode-project
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144087/available-documentation-tools-for-xcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displaying it live - not that I know of.

But as for generating Apple like documentation, the best I have found is [appledoc](http://www.gentlebytes.com) which I've been using for a year now. If accepts a wide range of commenting styles including Javadoc styles and can generate very Apple like documentation which it can also install directly into your Xcode help system.

Comment: 404 error not found!?

Comment: I've updated the comment to refer to the GentleBytes home page. Appledoc can be found there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it still works for Xcode 4 but for Xcode 3 you could generate API doc sets using [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html).

Apple has a set by step guide: [Using doxygen to Create Xcode Documentation Sets](http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html) on how to do it.

Comment: Wow, docSets looks like a big beast. I don't think I'll want to do this in my (for the moment) one-man project. I might have a look into Doxygen.

Comment: @fzwo: Actually it's pretty easy.  You use Doxygen to generate the API docs and then there are a couple of extra steps to create an Apple doc set.  These can be integrated into the build process.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) tool available from GitHub. Makes nice docsets.