# How to create class reference for iOS Project like NSDictionary Class Reference - Apple Developer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to discover the way how I can create the class reference for my project classes.

For example, NSDictionary Class Reference - Apple Developer.

Comment: you mean the documentation ? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174315/how-do-you-document-your-source-code-in-xcode

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813529/documentation-generator-for-objective-c There's really enough of similar questions.

Comment: You can create and keep it with the code/project/framwork or even documentation. Do you want to add your class reference with Apple's given class references?

Comment: I just wanted to save the documentation. In future, if requirement comes to add my class reference with Apple's documentation then I need to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

[AppleDoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) is the tool that makes it easiest to generate documentation that looks like what Apple produces. With it, you can create doc sets that match Apple's style and that you can install alongside other Documentation in Xcode.

There are a number of other popular doc tools, including DoxyGen and HeaderDoc (which is probably what Apple actually uses, and included with Xcode). There's a good [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/documentation/) on the subject, and plenty of information online as well.